# Tensorflow on visual studio code ( or jupyter notebook) with gpu acceleration

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, gpu

How can I active gpu acceleration on visual studio code (Windows 11) to compute neural networks with tensorflow?
gpu = nvidia gtx 1070 ti

Answer (score 0):

1. Download [NVIDIA cuDNN](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn)
2. Download [NVIDIA CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive)
3. Add the extracted CUDA folder to the system environment variable(To the bin directory)
4. install tensorflow package by using `pip install tensorflow`
5. Test:

   import tensorflow
   import tensorflow as tf

   print(tf.test.is_gpu_available())

If you get **True**, it means success.

Comment: I've done this, but it didn't work

Comment: @Vincenzo Picarelli Did you use Anaconda? Is the python environment selected correctly?

Comment: I'm using miniconda

Comment: @Vincenzo Picarelli Is there an error, or is the graphics card unrecognized or the acceleration invalid?